# How can I get the battery status after 1h?

Tags: android, timer

I want do develop an Android App, which calculates the battery app
So here's my idea how to do that: When the user starts the app, the app gets the battery level of the phone (For example: 80%). And after 1h the app gets the battery status again (Then it is for example: 76%). The calculation: in 1h the battery loses 4%, that means the battery will last about 20h (80/4)

I know, how to get the battery status, etc..
My question: How can I set the countdown for 1h in the background? There shouldn't be any textView where the countdown is displayed. The coundown needs to run in the background. How can I do that?

I googled and found this, but this isn't working: (I put these method in `onCreate()`

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            IntentFilter intFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Battery: " + level/4, Toast.LENGTH_LONG); // this is just, to check, if the countDown is still running
                    toast.show();
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Comment: Look up how to use the `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need register once your broadcast receiver.

```
       //in Oncreate
       ...
       IntentFilter intFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
       BatteryReceiver batteryReceiver = new BatteryReceiver();
       registerReceiver(batteryReceiver , intFilter);
       ...

       public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            int startlevel = 0;
            long lastUpdateTime = 0;
            boolean isStartCheck = false;
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(!isStartCheck){
                    startlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                    lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    isStartCheck = true;   
                } else {
                    if((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdateTime)/1000 > 3600) {
                    // 1h was going. do your work.
                    reset();
                    }
                }  
            }

            public void reset() {
                lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                isStartCheck = false;
                startLevel = 0;
            }

       }
```

Comment: why do we need another class for this?

Comment: Why not? It's flexible way. Actually you can implement this class in your Activity.

Comment: why do we need reset?

Comment: i implemented this in my code(Thanks for the code) and started the app. "App sopped". For this situation i tried to calculate the lifetime after only 10s. what can be the reason, that he stopped the app? 
He stopped the app after 21 seconds

Comment: it seems like that he gives me the error when he is on this line: `if((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdateTime)/1000 > 10)`

Comment: Can you provide to me your log?